# Comments as part of a post

Tags: posts, comments

Is there a way to show comments as part of a post, and not adding it with comments_template()?

Comment: I'm sure you can [query comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) and post them directly into the page template if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using either of them

[get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

[wp_list_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)